# Does a closed form solution for $x$ exist for $k\cdot\Bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{x}{y}}\Bigg) = x $?

Tags: roots, recreational-mathematics

In an engineering problem I was working on, I have found a function of three variables:

$$f(x, y, k) = k\cdot\Bigg(1-\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{x}{y}}\Bigg) = x $$

In certain applications, we hold $y$ and $k$ constant, and consider it to act as a function of one variable. In that case, is it possible to express the zeroes of the function $f(x) = 0$ in closed form in terms of $y$ and $k$? Of course the solutions can be found numerically, but it would be convenient to have a closed form if possible.

For example, in one case, $k=134201.63$ and $y=5\cdot10^4$. In this case, the zero occurs at approximately $x=101208.723$.

[image: Graph of the function example]

Comment: It has a closed form solution, but it won't be in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let set  $X=\frac xk$ and $a=\left(\frac 12\right)^{\frac ky}$

The equation becomes $1-a^X=X$

No set $U=1-X$ then $U=a^X=a^{1-U}=aa^{-U}\iff Ua^U=a$

Finally for $\alpha=\ln(a)$ and $V=\alpha U$ leads to $$Ve^V=a\ln(a)=\alpha e^\alpha$$

But $xe^x$ is not injective, its reciprocal the Lambert $W$ function has two branches $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

From the figures you have given we have $\alpha<-1$ so the two solutions are

- $V_1=W_{-1}(\alpha e^\alpha)=\alpha\implies U_1=1\implies x_1=0$
- $V_2=W_0(a\ln(a))\implies x_2=k\left(1-\dfrac{W_0(a\ln(a))}{\ln(a)}\right)$

*For other values of $a$, it may happen that the non-zero value is reached for $W_{-1}$ instead.*

You have to evaluate though, whether calculating this thing is more efficient than a numerical solving of the initial equation or even numerically solve the simpler $Ua^U=a$, I guess it all comes to whether you have a good implementation of the LambertW function on your platform or not.